# How to run two Apache web servers (httpd) in RedHat Linux?

Tags: apache, tomcat, multiple-instances

I configured Apache web servers 2.2 & 2.4 on RedHat Linux 6, both are working fine individually, and also connectors with Tomcat application servers working fine.

But the problem is when I started either 2.2 or 2.4, only one is working, next one shows error, already allotted memory, httpd is not running.. WHAT TO DO?

```
#/usr/local/apache2 ---@apache httpd 2.2.V 
#/usr/local/httpd24  ---@apache httpd 2.4.23V

#/etc/httpd ---------* What this folder is? And I have seen conf htttpd.conf folders also..
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the server might be pointing to same resources such as port. Change default port value to different  value and they run it .

Comment: yes, it is working fine...

But i have a small doubt, when i configured httpd, i have seen /etc/httpd..

what the purpose of this dir?

if the dir removes, httpd is not running, how to recover this dir?

thank you...

Comment: Short for HTTP daemon, a software program that runs in the background of a Web server and waits for incoming server requests. The daemon answers the requests automatically and serves the hypertext and multimedia documents over the Internet using HTTP.      http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/H/HTTPD.html

Comment: I believe, you may need to reinstall the HTTPD. but not very sure with this.